# возникает ошибка импорта библиотеки "discord",но при этом библиотека "selenium" импортируется успешно

Tags: python

сама ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "F:\Discord\discord.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import Discord ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Discord'

```
import Discord
from Discord import utils

import config

class MyClient( discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format( self.user))

    async def on_raw_reaction_add( self, payload):
     if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
            channel = self.get_channel( payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
            message = await channel.fetch_message( payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
            member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id= payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

            try:
                emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
                role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id= config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

                if(len([i for i in member.roles if i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                    print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))

            except KeyError as e:
                print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
            except Exception as e:
                print(repr(e))

    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))

        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

# RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: А где сам-то код?

Comment: поправил,проверяйте

Answer (score 0):

Установите модуль `discord`
Ваша ошибка сообщает, что модуля с таким именем не существует.

```py
python3 -m pip install discord.py
```

Или

```
python3.7 -m pip install discord.py
```

В зависимости от того, какая у Вас версия `python` стоит.

Comment: версия питона 3.8

Comment: @Nikita Raskolnik Для начала попробуйте использовать `pip install discord.py` для установки модуля.

Comment: всё выполнил,модуль был установлен,но почему то не импортируется

Comment: при этом импорт модуля selenium проходит успешно